# strange behaviour of "as" operator

Tags: c#, casting, prototyping

So I have the following code:

```
 /// <summary>
/// The 'Prototype' abstract class
/// </summary>
abstract class ColorPrototype
{
    public abstract ColorPrototype Clone();
}

/// <summary>
/// The 'ConcretePrototype' class
/// </summary>
class Color : ColorPrototype
{
    private int _red;
    private int _green;
    private int _blue;

    // Constructor
    public Color(int red, int green, int blue)
    {
        this._red = red;
        this._green = green;
        this._blue = blue;
    }

    // Create a shallow copy
    public override ColorPrototype Clone()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(
          "Cloning color RGB: {0,3},{1,3},{2,3}",
          _red, _green, _blue);

        return this.MemberwiseClone() as ColorPrototype;
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Prototype manager
/// </summary>
class ColorManager
{
    private Dictionary<string, ColorPrototype> _colors =
      new Dictionary<string, ColorPrototype>();

    // Indexer
    public ColorPrototype this[string key]
    {
        get { return _colors[key]; }
        set { _colors.Add(key, value); }
    }
}
```

And in the main method I have:

```
ColorManager colormanager = new ColorManager();

// Initialize with standard colors
colormanager["red"] = new Color(255, 0, 0);

// User clones selected colors
ColorPrototype p1 = colormanager["red"].Clone();
bool isColor = p1 is Prototype.Color;
Color color1 = p1 as Color;
```

My question is why the variable p1 has type `Color` (`isColor` is true) if in the clone method I cast the result to `ColorPrototype` (`return this.MemberwiseClone() as ColorPrototype;`) ?

Reference: http://www.dofactory.com/net/prototype-design-pattern

Comment: An instance of `ColorPrototype` *is* also a `Color` because `ColorProtoype` derives from `Color`. The same way that an `Rectangle` is still a `Shape`.

Comment: @haim770 color extends ColorPrototype, so Color is a ColorPrototype and not viceversa, unless I use contravariance, right?

Comment: Sorry, I misread it as `ColorPrototype : Color`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> if in the clone method I cast the result to ColorPrototype

Because even though you cast `p1` to a `ColorPrototype`, the runtime type of `p1` is still of type `Color`. Casting a reference type allows you to view a type `T` as type `U`, but it doesn't alter the underlying runtime type.

Comment: Thank you. "Casting allows you to view a type T as type U, but it doesn't alter the underlying runtime type" made it clear to me. I will mark this as an answer in a few minutes.

Answer (score 3):

`this.MemberwiseClone()` returns you `Color` object. So `p1` is actually a `Color`.

It does not matter if you upcast it to `ColorPrototype`. Its runtime type is still `Color`. This is the same as:

```
string s = "foo";
object o = s as object;
// runtime o type is still string
```

Comment: yes, but you have after: as ColorPrototype so this is somehow a safe cast... So why is still a color?